# NullPointerException In ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner

I have tried to get data from Firebase, and data will show in 'spinner'
data showed in spinner

but

Fragment work (Penilaian Fragment), but when I change fragment and click dialog in other fragments it shows error like this

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif, PID: 7214
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.getBaseContext()' on a null object reference
        at com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif.PenilaianFragment$5.onEvent(PenilaianFragment.java:377)
        at com.sariazhariyah.eassessmentinteraktif.PenilaianFragment$5.onEvent(PenilaianFragment.java:366)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:1045)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

in code, I wrote an array adapter like this

```
arraykelas.add("--Pilih Kelas--");
                      for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:queryDocumentSnapshots){
                          arraykelas.add(documentSnapshot.get("kelas").toString());
                      }

                      kelasarrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arraykelas);
                      kelasspinner.setAdapter(kelasarrayadapter);
```

Comment: add activity as context like activity as Context,

Comment: i am sorry,how to add it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to set spinner adapter your activity context gets null this can be possible when you fetch data using another thread and when the response comes the thread calls the method you called but your fragment is not in stack and thats why the activities context is also null after your response comes either you can cancel network requests in your fragments onDestroy() or if you want a simple solution you can check getActivity()!=null before using the context anywhere

Answer (score 0):

When you change fragment, your function load data and try to put it in spinner. But spinner in enother fragment. try to solve it. I can make mistake because it's not enough code here.